# could not connect to MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mean-stack, meanjs, mean.io

I have an issue using the mean.io tutorial to create the default mean app. i have mongodb install what could be ths issue this is the error.That is the error below. Thanks.

```
PS C:\Users\Truparse Creative\Documents\myMeanProject\lisavogue> npm test

> mean@0.5.5 test C:\Users\Truparse Creative\Documents\myMeanProject\lisavogue
> gulp test

Invoking gulp - development
[08:40:17] Using gulpfile ~\Documents\myMeanProject\lisavogue\gulpfile.js
[08:40:17] Starting 'startServer'...
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
**Could not connect to MongoDB. Please ensure mongod is running and restart MEAN app.**
```

Comment: Have you tried connecting to the mongo shell from command line ? Please do try and share the response as well.

Comment: Is your mongo server running before executing above commands?

Answer (score 0):

in your terminal, type `mongod` to start mongodb and leave it running. Then, open a new terminal tab(or window) and try running your application again.

You need the mongodb server to be running to be able to use it. It looks like you're not running it.

You can also access the mongo shell by running `mongo` in your terminal to look at the server, collections, perform queries, etc.